# Cross-Origin Request Blocked: ....(Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missinG

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, cors, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

I'm working on yeoman angular generator (frontend) and laravel (backend)

#### Controller function

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
     //Wat to write here
    }
service file

  .service('registerservice', function ($http, EnvironmentConfig ) {
  function register(user) {
      
        return $http({
               url: EnvironmentConfig.api + 'api/v1/register',
               method: 'post',
                data : $httpParamSerializerJQLike(user)           
               })
                ;}
        return {
            register: register       
        };
  });
```

ERROR:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
> the remote resource at
> localhost/angular/blog/public/index.php/api/v1/register. (Reason: CORS
> header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question lacks on information to provide help. Please provide error messages and a real "question" so we know what's wrong. Also consider to take the [tour].

Comment: i m getting this error......

Comment: Which error? try to show to us the error message

Comment: Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":null,"status":-1,"config":{"method":"POST","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"http://localhost/angular/blog/public/index.php/api/v1/register","data":"city=gjj&name=tyhj&pass=ghj","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8"}},"statusText":""}

Comment: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost/angular/blog/public/index.php/api/v1/register. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Comment: You should edit your post and put the error in your answer